# JAXB throwing InstantiationException trying to marshal xsi:type based on abstract class

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, moxy, xsitype

I am having an issue with using inheritance and JAXB unmarshalling. I have read the number of examples (specifically a much-reference blog at http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/11/jaxb-and-inheritance-using-xsitype.html and a very similar SO question here: [JAXB xsi:type subclass unmarshalling not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11219074/jaxb-xsitype-subclass-unmarshalling-not-working)) and am still having difficulties.

Like many of these other questions, I am trying to create an XML representation of an object whose fields rely on subclasses for information. I do not know at compile time what the concrete subclass implementation will be, so things like XmlSeeAlso is not really available.

In my test case I have a Root class with an abstract class (A) that has a concrete subtype (B):

```
@XmlRootElement
@ToString
    public class Root {

    private A theClass;

    public A getTheClass() {
        return theClass;
    }

    public void setTheClass(A theClass) {
        this.theClass = theClass;
    }
}

@ToString
public abstract class A {

}

@XmlRootElement
@ToString
public class B extends A {
    private  String b = "from B-" + System.currentTimeMillis()
    public String getB() {
       return b;
    }

    public void setB(String b) {
         this.b = b;
    }
}
```

Where @ToString are annotations from project Lombok.

I can marshall with no problem:

```
@Test
public void marshallTest() {

    try {
        Root r = new Root();
        B b = new B();

        r.setTheClass(b);
        Class<?>[] classArray = new Class<?> [] { Root.class, B.class };

        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(classArray);
        Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();

        try (FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(JAXB_TEST_XML)) {
            marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
            marshaller.marshal(r, fw);
        }

        try(StringWriter sw = new StringWriter() ) {
            marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
            marshaller.marshal(r, sw);
            log.debug("{}", sw.toString());
        }

    } catch (IOException | JAXBException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        fail(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Which produces the following xml:

```
<root>
   <theClass xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="b">
      <b>from B-1375211003868</b>
   </theClass>
</root>
```

When I try to unmarshall (using MOXY JAXB implemntation) I get:

```
This class does not define a public default constructor, or the constructor raised an exception.
Internal Exception: java.lang.InstantiationException
Descriptor: XMLDescriptor(xml.A --> [])
```

With the following code:

```
@Test
public void unmarshall() {

    try {
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(new Class<?>[] {Root.class, A.class});
        DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

        documentBuilderFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        DocumentBuilder db = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

        Root r = null;
        try(BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(JAXB_TEST_XML))) {
            Document doc = db.parse(bis);
            Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
            JAXBElement<?> result = unmarshaller.unmarshal(doc, Root.class);
            r = (Root) result.getValue();
        }

        assertTrue(r != null & r.getTheClass() != null && r.getTheClass() instanceof B);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        fail(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

I have tried making the unmarshalling namespace aware (as with [JAXB xsi:type subclass unmarshalling not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11219074/jaxb-xsitype-subclass-unmarshalling-not-working)a) which has not worked. I have tried using XmlElementRef which does not work either.  I have tried the latest glassfish api and implementations downloaded from maven central (2.2.8). I have tried the MOXY eclipse persistence JAXB implementation. Neither have worked.  I have tried unmarshalling without using a document builder which does not work as well.  I have tried passing the Root.class and A.class into the JAXB context which also does not work.

I have a feeling that I have a fundamental misconception about what is going on. Any hints or ideas would be appreciated.  Thank you.

- Chooks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE 2**

You could use a library to determine the subclasses dynamically and pass that result to MOXy to build the `JAXBContext`.  Below is an enhancement request that was entered suggesting Jandex for this purpose.

- https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=412236

---

**UPDATE 1**

There was an issue prior to EclipseLink 1.2.0 (released October 23, 2009) where that exception could be thrown even though everything was setup correctly.

---

You just need to make the `JAXBContext` aware of the `B` class.  One way to do this is to leverage the `@XmlSeeAlso` annotation on the `A` class.

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSeeAlso;

@XmlSeeAlso({B.class})
public abstract class A {
```

}

You can also include `B` in the classes used to bootstrap the `JAXBContext`:

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Root.class, B.class);
```

Comment: I want to avoid putting the concrete class reference in at compile time (see second paragraph in question). I am using moxy 2.5.0 from maven central (group id of org.eclipse.persistence and artifact Id of org.eclipse.persistence.moxy). I thought that the xsi:type specification would allow the JAXBContext to look for classes that match that type. If that is not the case then I may need to rethink what I am doing and use a different approach other than XML. But for the record - yes -- explicitly telling the JAXBContext about the concrete class makes things work.

Comment: @chooks - I have updated my answer.  Potentially you could use another library to determine the classes, and pass the result of that to MOXy to create the `JAXBContext`.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to jandex. I had thought about trying to do something similar, but thought that I was probably doing something wrong with my unmarshalling and xsi:type.  Thanks for taking the time to address my question.

Comment: I have the same problem and nothing works. I'm using jaxb-ri-2.1-2 (which is what Maven picked for me) and am schema driven. xjc has declared the abstract class as 
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "BaseProgramGroupTypeType")
@XmlSeeAlso({
    ProgramGroupTypeType.class
})
public abstract class BaseProgramGroupTypeType {
}